# sed: modify a file using contents of another file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, posix

I've got a script which writes an ip address to a file `ip.txt`

I want to replace an ip address in an html file with the ip from `ip.txt`.

I've got a sed regex expression that matches an ip address, and I want to replace this matched text with the contents of `ip.txt`:

`"s/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}//g"`

How can I get `sed` to pull the contents of `ip.txt` and put it in the expression `s/<search>/<*HERE*>/g`?

Is there a better way to do it than this?

```
sed -e "s/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/"`cat ip.txt`"/g"
```

Comment: I'd stick with what you have working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the IP into a shell variable before running the sed command. Assuming that ip.txt is a single line containing only the IP address:

```
read -r ip < ip.txt
sed -e "s/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/$ip/g" file.html > newfile.html
mv newfile.html file.html
```

Comment: If you are just learning about read, you will likely find this FAQ informative: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Why was my post edited to use sed -i? The -i is a GNU extension to sed that may not be available on the OPs platform.

Answer (score 4):

Not much of an improvement, but you can replace

```
"`cat ip.txt`"
```

with

```
$(<ip_txt)
```

which will be replaced with the contents of the file and is slightly more efficient than using `cat`.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX `sed` (and therefore most of the available implementations of `sed`) supports the `r file` command to read a file when a line is matched.  As long as you don't mind have the result containing newlines either side of where the IP address was, you could easily enough do it using `r`.  The description says:

> [1addr]**r** *rfile*
>
> Copy the contents of *rfile* to standard output as described previously. If *rfile* does not exist or cannot be read, it shall be treated as if it were an empty file, causing no error condition.

This means that you don't get a chance to edit the contents of the file, whereas if it was read into the pattern space or hold space, you could could then modify the data.

This being the case, your command line substitution is about as good as you can do.